Finding the complete Keplerian orbit from position and velocity
Question's aim summary: finding 5 points on any Keplerian orbit so I can use the "Five points define a conic" method to get the complete conic. I already solved this for the case of an ellipse, but for a hyperbola I can only find 3 points.
Problem description: I implemented a simple Newtonian gravity simulation (using velocity Verlet integration). I would like to predict the orbit of a smaller object of mass $m$ around a massive object of mass $M$ ($m\ll M$). The heavier object is located at the origin. I know the initial position $\vec{r}_{0}$ and velocity $\vec{v}_{0}$ of the orbiting object, and the standard gravitational parameter $\mu$.
What I have so far: Assume I work in the orbital plane, so all quantities are given in this plane (i.e. all vectors are in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$). My goal is to find 5 points on the orbit. Here's a figure with all magnitudes I found for an elliptical orbit:

The first point I have is $\vec{r}_{0}$, which I will call $\mathbf{P}_{1}$. The next point to find is the perihelion of the orbit $\mathbf{P}_{2}$ by using the eccentricity vector:
$$\vec{e} = \frac{\vec{v}_{0}\times\left(\vec{r}_{0}\times\vec{v}_{0}\right)}{\mu}\label{eq:ecc_vec} - \hat{r}_{0}$$
Since $\vec{e}$ is pointing from the origin to $\mathbf{P}_{2}$, I only need to find the periapsis of the orbit, $r_{\text{p}}$. This can be done using the semi-major axis $a$:
$$a = \frac{r(1+e\cos(\theta))}{1-e^{2}},$$
where $e=\left|\vec{e}\right|, r=\left|\vec{r}_{0}\right|,$ and $\theta=\arccos\left(\frac{\vec{r}_{0}\cdot\vec{e}}{er}\right)$. Therefore, $\mathbf{P}_{2}=a\hat{e}$ (where $\hat{e}$ is the unit vector in direction of $\vec{e}$).
The next point $\mathbf{P}_{3}$ can be found via orbital symmetry by rotating $\vec{r}_{0}$ by $-2\theta$ (i.e. in opposite to the orbit's orientation) about the origin.
From here, I can find more points only for an elliptical orbit.
$\mathbf{P}_{4}$ is the apoapsis, which can be found by subtracting $2a\hat{e}$ from the periapsis ($\mathbf{P}_{2}$).
For the last point, I use either one of the co-vertices. They are positioned at $\mathbf{P}_{\text{c}}\pm b\hat{d}$, where $\mathbf{P}_{\text{c}}$ is the center of the ellipse, $b$ is the semi-minor axis and $\hat{d}$ is a vector orthogonal to $\vec{e}$. All these can be found rather easily:
$$
\begin{aligned}
b &= a\sqrt{1-e^2},\\
\mathbf{P}_{\text{c}} &= \mathbf{P}_{2} - c\hat{e},\\
\vec{d} &= \begin{bmatrix}-e_{y}\\e_{x}\end{bmatrix}.
\end{aligned}
$$
(where $c$ is the linear eccentricity $c=\sqrt{a^{2}-b^{2}}$ and $\vec{e} = \begin{bmatrix}e_{x}\\e_{y}\end{bmatrix}$)
And that's it for an ellipse: I got 6 points, and can choose any 5 of them to use in the "Five points define a conic" method to find the exact shape of the orbit.
However, as I mentioned earlier for an orbit with $e\geq1$ I'm missing two points.
I'm pretty sure that there is a way to get two more points on a hyperbolic orbit, and would appreciate any pointers on how to find them using the information I have (so $\vec{r}_{0},\ \vec{v}_{0},\ \mu$ and assuming the massive object is at the origin).

Since you are working in the orbital plane, once you have $a$ and $e$ you can just choose any $\theta$ to get the $r$ value (your equation for $a$).

Yes, I feel silly for not even considering the basic orbit equation. Ooopsy
